# What happened to custom CSS in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

So I'm a developer trying to help out a non-profit that has a site in wordpress. The Wordpress version is a little out of date (they don't have 4.7.1).

I updated some css in one of the theme files (a small change, just wanted to see if I could make a change happen before I went in and did larger changes). I pressed update file and everything seemed to be ok.

I then checked the website, and the change had not propagated. I then went back to check the css if I'd made a mistake..but then I saw this-

[image]

There's no CSS!??

But when I go to the site, the css is still there and the theme is still applied.

What is going on?

EDIT

These are the other themes?

[image]

I have also pasted a backed up version of the CSS - got a message saying the file was updated...but nothing happened. Why?

Also why am I getting downvoted? I followed exactly what wordpress expects me to do and the behaviour is totally unexpected.

Comment: This file probably could be child theme's css.

Comment: I updated question with what I see when I try and select other themes. If this was a child theme - then shouldn't the old theme still exist? I also pasted a backup of the css for this and updated...got a message saying the file was updated, but nothing was added.

Comment: Any cache issues?

Comment: this was stupid. Turns out the third party hadn't set a limit on how much storage could be used for emails - so they had no disk storage left. Which meant any update was simply replaced with the same file of 0KB. I proved this by making space and updating the theme css. However, now the change will not show up in word press (likely a caching issue with cpanel or wordpress). Got any advice?